# Query with multiple between clauses

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

My ORM looks like the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, TIMESTAMP, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    timestamp = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
    object = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('object.id'))

class Object(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'object'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    version = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    setting = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    history = relationship('ObjectHistory', backref='history')

class ObjectHistory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'object_history'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    version = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    setting = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    start = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
    end = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    object = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('object.id'))
```

And my data looks like the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
import datetime

engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost/')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

obj = Object(version='0001', setting='some')

# populate database
data = [
    obj,
    Data(value='a', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2017,6,21,12,0,0), object=obj.id),
    Data(value='b', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2017,6,21,13,0,0), object=obj.id),
    Data(value='c', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2017,6,21,14,0,0), object=obj.id),
    Data(value='d', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2017,6,21,15,0,0), object=obj.id),
    ObjectHistory(version='0001', setting='any', start=datetime.datetime(2017,6,21,11,30,0), end=datetime.datetime(2017,6,21,12,30,0)),
    ObjectHistory(version='0002', setting='some', start=datetime.datetime(2017,6,21,12,30,0), end=datetime.datetime(2017,6,21,13,30,0)),
    ObjectHistory(version='0001', setting='some', start=datetime.datetime(2017,6,21,13,30,0), end=None),
]

session.add_all(data)
session.commit()
```

I want to query all `Data` for when `Object` had a specific version. As you can see, the same version can occur multiple times in the history, and I want to have all Data entries during which a specific version was used.

I thought something along these lines:

```
version = '0001'

# get the start and end timestamps during which object had this version
between_these = session.query(ObjectHistory.start, ObjectHistory.end) \
    .filter(ObjectHistory.version == version)

# and then somehow query Data between these timestamps
# so that data contains the Data rows with values 'a', 'c', and 'd'
# this won't work
data = session.query(Data) \
    .filter(Data.timestamp.between(between_these.start, between_these.end)).all()
```

However I don't think that approach will work work because there can be multiple start and end timestamps. I think I need to use `or_` (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_), however I can't seem to figure out how to apply it in this case. Is it at all possible and if so, how?

**edit: so the desired output are the `Data` rows during which `Data.object` had version '0001', in the example those are the `Data` rows in which `Data.value` is 'a', 'c' and 'd'.**

Comment: what does exception say?

Comment: i think it fails because you are trying to filter string between timestamps

Comment: btw why `Data.timestamp` is string?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Sorry you are right, I see I made a mistake in my example. `Data.timestamp` is a `TIMESTAMP` as well. I edited my question.

Comment: so can you provide exception's traceback?

Comment: also it seems like your imports are messy: there are `ObjectHistory` and `models.ObjectHistory`

Comment: how should we interpret `NULL` value for `end` column? +infinity?

Comment: please, add desired output, it is still not clear what are you trying to achieve

Comment: NULL value for end column basically means there is no end timestamp yet, so yes +infinity.

Comment: I tried to make the example as general and minimal as possible, but in the process it apparently turned out as vague as possible, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is that `between_these` object has `Query` type, i.e. it hasn't been executed and have no attributes `start`/`end`.

We can do the following:

- create subquery from `between_these` object and then use it in filter,
- use **PostgreSQL**'s [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) function for `ObjectHistory.end` with `NULL` values

so it can be like

```
between_these = (session.query(ObjectHistory.start,
                               ObjectHistory.end)
                 .filter(ObjectHistory.version == '0001')
                 .subquery('between_these'))

data = (session.query(Data)
        .filter(Data.timestamp.between(between_these.c.start,
                                       func.coalesce(between_these.c.end,
                                                     datetime.max)))
        .all())
```

this will work but we will never know relation between `object_history` record and filtered `data` records.

If you want for each filtered `Data` object to have `ObjectHistory` object on which filtration was based then we can query for both like

```
data = (session.query(Data, ObjectHistory)
        .filter(ObjectHistory.version == '0001')
        .filter(Data.timestamp.between(ObjectHistory.start,
                                       func.coalesce(ObjectHistory.end,
                                                     datetime.max))))
        .all())
```

(we don't need `between_these` object here)

or if we want to know additionally only time interval

```
data = (session.query(Data, ObjectHistory.start, ObjectHistory.end)
        .filter(ObjectHistory.version == '0001')
        .filter(Data.timestamp.between(ObjectHistory.start,
                                       func.coalesce(ObjectHistory.end,
                                                     datetime.max))))
        .all())
```

## Tests

At first imports and adding initializers to models

```
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, TIMESTAMP, create_engine, func
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import make_url
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    timestamp = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, value, timestamp):
        self.value = value
        self.timestamp = timestamp


class Object(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'object'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    version = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    setting = Column(String(8), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, version, setting):
        self.version = version
        self.setting = setting


class ObjectHistory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'object_history'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    version = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    setting = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    start = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
    end = Column(TIMESTAMP)

    def __init__(self, version, setting, start, end):
        self.version = version
        self.setting = setting
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
```

then initialization of database & creating session

```
db_uri = make_url('postgresql://username:password@host:5432/database')
engine = create_engine(db_uri)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = session_factory()
```

after that we add our test data to database

```
session.add_all([
    # first `Data` object
    Data(value='a',
         timestamp=datetime(2017, 6, 21, 12, 0, 0)),
    # second `Data` object
    Data(value='b',
         timestamp=datetime(2017, 6, 21, 13, 0, 0)),
    # third `Data` object
    Data(value='c',
         timestamp=datetime(2017, 6, 21, 14, 0, 0)),
    # fourth `Data` object
    Data(value='d',
         timestamp=datetime(2017, 6, 21, 15, 0, 0)),
    Object(version='0001',
           setting='some'),
    ObjectHistory(version='0001',
                  setting='any',
                  start=datetime(2017, 6, 21, 11, 30, 0),
                  end=datetime(2017, 6, 21, 12, 30, 0)),
    ObjectHistory(version='0002',
                  setting='some',
                  start=datetime(2017, 6, 21, 12, 30, 0),
                  end=datetime(2017, 6, 21, 13, 30, 0)),
    ObjectHistory(version='0001',
                  setting='some',
                  start=datetime(2017, 6, 21, 13, 30, 0),
                  end=None)])
session.commit()
```

then generating query and fetching it

```
between_these = (session.query(ObjectHistory.start,
                               ObjectHistory.end)
                 .filter(ObjectHistory.version == '0001')
                 .subquery('between_these'))

data = (session.query(Data)
        .filter(Data.timestamp.between(between_these.c.start,
                                       func.coalesce(between_these.c.end,
                                                     datetime.max)))
        .all())
```

finally – assertions

```
assert len(data) == 3
assert all(datum.value in {'a', 'c', 'd'}
           for datum in data)
```

So as we can see `data` object consists of first, third and fourth `Data` objects.

Comment: Thanks for your help already, it helped me understand the subquery syntax. However, using your code I still only get one of the `Data` entries during which a specific version was used. Sorry if my question/example wasn't clear enough, I edited my post to add some example data to the database, which hopefully makes clear what my problem is.

Comment: That's great. I had no idea sqlalchemy was that powerful, I thought I would at least need fancy stuff, but this code is actually still readable. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Semi: `SQLALchemy` is a great library for simple models and queries, you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your model doesn't have any apparent relations between the tables.

To query data for when object has a specific version, there must be a relation from `Object` -> `ObjectHistory`, to query the *data* associated with a specific *version* of `Object` there must be a relation between `ObjectHistory` -> `Data`.

The altered schema should look like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, TIMESTAMP, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Object(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'object'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    version = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    setting = Column(String(8), nullable=False)

class ObjectHistory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'object_history'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    object_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Object.id))
    version = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    setting = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    start = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
    end = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)

class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    object_history_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ObjectHistory.id))
    value = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    timestamp = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
```

Then you can write the appropriate `SELECT` query:

```
version = '0001'
object_id = 1
stmt = session.query(Object.id,
                     ObjectHistory.version,
                     ObjectHistory.start,
                     ObjectHistory.end,
                     Data.id,
                     Data.value,
                     Data.timestamp) \
    .filter(Object.id == ObjectHistory.object_id) \
    .filter(Data.object_history_id = ObjectHistory.id) \
    .filter(Object.id == object_id)
    .filter(ObjectHistory.version == version)
```

**However, this is but 1 way of setting up this kind of data model.**

Alternatively, `Object` -> `Data` can be related & the `Object` -> `ObjectHistory` related as above, with the relationship between `Data` & `ObjectHistory` requiring the `BETWEEN` operator.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In reality there are some relationships between the objects, I left them out to keep it my question more general. But because it does seem to be relevant now, I have added the relationships to the example.